# in a custom lisp function how to run command after gdb loaded

Tags: gdb

below are my set up for launching gdb in Emacs.

```
(defun debug-gdb-advanced ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)         ; close all other panes
  (split-window-horizontally)    ; split pane left right
  (other-window 1)               ; switch to right pane
  (split-window-vertically)      ; split pane top down
  (debug-gdb)                    ; open
  (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t) ; anchor the gdb window, never let it switch buffer
  (other-window 2)               ; switch to left pane
  (gdb-display-stack-buffer)     ; open stack buffer
  (other-window 1))              ; switch to gdb pane
```

but I also want to run the following after gdb has initialized

```
(defun closeUnnecessaryBuffers ()
  (interactive)
  (setq kill-buffer-query-functions nil)
  (kill-buffer (shell "*breakpoints of *"))
  (kill-buffer (shell "*threads of *"))
  (kill-buffer (shell "input/output of*")))
```

is there a way to fold the second function into the first one without mannually waiting gdb fully initialized.

Comment: (1st) The global `(setq kill-buffer-query-functions nil)`. is rather drastic in a function that just closes some buffers. Maybe, you should use `(let (kill-buffer-query-functions) ...close the buffers you want...)` instead. It restrics the nil-binding of `kill-buffer-query-functions` to the body of the `let`-form. (2nd) `(shell "*breakpoints of *")` looks very strange to me. Maybe, you actually want something like `(let ((buf (get-buffer "*breakpoints of *")) (when buf (kill-buffer buf))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook variable `gdb-mode-hook` is probably what you are looking for.

Citation from the [GUD-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GUD-Customization.html)

> On startup, GUD runs one of the following hooks: gdb-mode-hook, if you are using GDB; dbx-mode-hook, if you are using DBX; sdb-mode-hook, if you are using SDB; xdb-mode-hook, if you are using XDB; guiler-mode-hook for Guile REPL debugging; perldb-mode-hook, for Perl debugging mode; pdb-mode-hook, for PDB; jdb-mode-hook, for JDB. See Hooks.

Maybe, it should be added that `(run-hooks 'gdb-mode-hook)` is the last action in `gdb`.

You can add the function `closeUnnecessaryBuffers` to the hook variable in the following way:

```el
(add-hook 'gdb-mode-hook #'closeUnnecessaryBuffers)
```

Note that you can avoid opening many windows for gdb by switching `gdb-many-windows` off. You can do that via `M-x customize-option` `gdb-many-windows`. You do not get rid of the additional buffers like `"* breakpoints of *"` by that. I am not sure whether those buffers are essential for gdb and whether you shouldn't kill them.

Comment: These buffers actually shouldn't be closed, otherwise gdb doesn't function properly. My intention is to speed up gdb-mi by closing these buffers (the code base I'm working on is huge, gdb-mi can be very sluggish sometimes). classic gdb without many windows is fast and smooth, but it does not provide the perks like clickable stack frames.